# Program to find all indexes of element using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, find, element

I have to write program to find all indexes, where given element occurs. 
I' ve written this function:

```
int find(const int* tab, int size, int to_find)
{
  if (size<1 || tab==NULL) return -2;
  int i, counter = 0;
  for (i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
    if (to_find==*(tab + i)) return i;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This function only returns first occurence of element, but I want to it returns every element. How can I do this?

Comment: "*How can I do this?*" start by not returning after the 1st element has been found?

Comment: Use a second array, where use store the indexes found?

Comment: Think about what the results are logically. You need to represent multiple locations of an array. How do you want it to look? A list or array of indices? The simplest thing to do is to use an array and you'll need to indicate how many elements (matches) are in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Your `find()` function as it stands is fine. Aside that it should not return 0 to indicate that no values have been found, as 0 is a valid index.

To have it not just only find the 1st occurrence of matching elements, modify it in a way that you can tell it where to start its search and call it repetitively to let the caller decide what to do with the hit(s).

Answer (score 1):

A function can only return one value and then the control shifts to the statement following the function call. In order to get all the required values, a separate array can be used. Another way could be to modify the function to check for one value at a time. A loop can be used to call the function in each iteration.